# Can't load library from ctypes

Tags: python, c++, dll, ctypes

I would like to use a C++ API from python.
The files that I have are XX.dll, XX.lib and XX.h

The only info that I have are :

> Notes: To use the XX functions inside your C++ project you must integrate the
> XX Object file library "XX.lib" and XX header file "XX.h".
> The XX DLL must be add in your computer environment but not necessarily
> in the same folder of the Visual Studio project.

Naively I tried to take the .dll and to use `ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("XX.dll")` but when I do that python tries (and fails) to load mscvr90.dll.

I think the problem with mscvr90.dll is related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/27392347/12452727 but I don't know how to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a quick fix.
Apparently, the idea is to use "mt.exe" to incorporate a manifest in the dll.

The manifest "XX.dll.manifest"

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type='win32' name='Microsoft.VC90.CRT' version='9.0.21022.8' processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b' />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
</assembly>
```

And the command needed is
`mt.exe -manifest XX.dll.manifest -outputresource:XX.dll;2`